# 1 function prim's algorithm python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, prims-algorithm

i tried to make a 1 function prims algorithm in python but it doesn't seem to be working

```
def prim(edges):
    inGraph = ['A']
    discovered = []
    results = []
    counter = 0
    while True:
            tmplist = []
            for i in edges:
                    if inGraph[counter] in i:
                            discovered.append(i)
                            tmplist.append(i)
            for i in tmplist:
                    edges.remove(i)
            tmp = []
            for i in discovered:
                    tmp.append(i[2])
            mini = tmp.index(min(tmp))
            alpha = discovered[mini][0]
            beta = discovered[mini][1]

            if alpha not in inGraph or beta not in inGraph:
                    if alpha in inGraph:
                            inGraph.append(beta)
                    elif beta in inGraph:
                            inGraph.append(alpha)
                    results.append(discovered[mini])
            discovered.pop(mini)
            if discovered == []:
                    break
            counter+=1

    return (inGraph, results)
```

print [['A', 'B', 1], ['A', 'C', 102], ['B', 'C', 4], ['C', 'F', 2], ['B', 'F', 1], ['F', 'E', 1]]
print prim([['A', 'B', 1], ['A', 'C', 102], ['B', 'C', 4], ['C', 'F', 2], ['B', 'F', 1], ['F', 'E', 1]])

the problem lies somewhere with discovered, either the if statement checking to see if it's empty or removing an element from it. I'm just not sure where to put it

Comment: Never **alter a list while you iterate over it**: do not call `edges.remove(..)` while you loop over it.

Comment: Furthermore you algorithm is rather inefficient.

Comment: efficiency doesn't matter and it's not editing though a for loop

Comment: yeah I know but the iterator **has a contract** that you are not allowed to alter the list in the meanwhile.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating).

Comment: you call **remove** since the iterator internally stores an index, it will start to make jumps of more than one element.

Comment: it's fine that's not the problem

Comment: even if it is not the problem for now I can generate a testcase within two minutes that will make it a problem... (actually there are even programs that can generate such cases :)

Comment: the problem is with discovered

Comment: of course: since you modify the `edges` list while iterating over it, **not all elements will be iterated**, and thus not **all** edges can be discovered. The one problem is linked (if not completely linked) to the other :)

Comment: can you tell me how to fix it, you can't just delete edges.remove(i)

Comment: what about constructing a temporary list of items you have to remove later in the process when the loop has ended?

Comment: do i replace edges with the temp list after or does it stay the same?

Comment: In the list you store each edge you plan to remove, next you iterate over the temp list and remove the edges from the `edges` list. Next you can throw away the temp list.

Comment: is there anything wrong with the edited code?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine only one vertex is connected with 'A', say 'B'. So, at first iteration, you will have only one edge in discovered. After adding 'B' to inGraph, you are popping that only edge from discovered.

So your discovered == [] becomes true and loop breaks, even though there might still be thousand edges connected with 'B'.

To terminate the main loop, calculate the no of vertex and break if len(inGraph)==no_of_vertex.

To do that, you can:

```
V = set()
for e in edges:
    v.add(e[0])
    v.add(e[1])
no_of_vertex = len(V)
V = None #To help garbage collector
```

Comment: so where do i put the if statement or the `discovered.pop(mini)`

Comment: would this just be added near the end of the function?

Comment: i put it at the end and got this error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prim.py", line 40, in <module>
    print prim([['A', 'B', 1], ['A', 'C', 102], ['B', 'C', 4], ['D', 'B', 7], ['D', 'F', 240], ['C', 'F', 2], ['B', 'F', 1], ['F', 'E', 1]])
  File "prim.py", line 17, in prim
    mini = tmp.index(min(tmp))
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence`

Comment: at the beginning of function, before while loop starts.